# ActionMailer .net mvc giving error, Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, actionmailer

When i am sending mail using ActionMailer.Net.Mvc getting a error "Value does not fall within the expected range." below is code.

```
               var context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;

                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current = context;
                    new MailController().NewsLetter("demo@gmail.com", objNewsModel).Deliver();
                });



    public class MailController : MailerBase
    {
           public EmailResult NewsLetter(string EmailAddress, NewsModel objNewsModel)
           {
               To.Clear();
                To.Add(EmailAddress);
                BCC.Add("demo@demo.com");
                From = "demodemo@demo.com";
                Subject = "Latest News";

                return Email("NewsLetter", objNewsModel); 
   //this (return Email("NewsLetter", objNewsModel);)line giving a error 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with an empty custom view Newsletter.txt.cshtml and it works perfect. Try it with an empty view, maybe there is a problem displaying the items.

Please keep in mind also that the ActionMailer is not maintained.

Comment: Thanks your replay Peppi. I tired with empty custom view Newsletter.txt.cshtml  or Newsletter.html.cshtml but its giving same error.
One more thing if i debug the code one by one step then some time its working fine. But if i run without debug then always its giving error ("Value does not fall within the expected range").

Comment: I also see it outputs an exception: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Web.dll but the email generates fine (I put it in a folder).

Comment: I think error is coming below code       Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current = context;
                    new MailController().NewsLetter("demo@gmail.com", objNewsModel).Deliver();
                });

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2Who0lUq1R8dHBIdHpSQ2JMVlU/view?usp=sharing

Saves the mails in d: folder(Web.config setting)

Comment: You can try it in the same thread, you will see what is the error is.

Comment: If i use (wait) this below code then its working fine but i want *new thread every time different thread *                                                  Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                        {
                            System.Web.HttpContext.Current = context;
                            new MailController().NewsLetter("karans@gmail.com", objNewsModel).Deliver();
                        }).Wait();